# Is it true as entropy increases things become more symmetric?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is it true that as entropy increases in a particular domain (say, the universe or a given box) so do the symmetries within this domain? Are there exceptions?

Say I'm looking at a rotational symmetry. I'm examining a circle that is colored red on the right, green in the center and blue on the left. It's not symmetric in regard to rotation. Now I mix the colors evenly in all directions. It is less ordered but now it is rotationally symmetric. 
Is this a general principle?

Comment: I think the general principle is that entropy is akin to uniformity or sameness. In terms of available energy, if the energy density is the same everywhere, you can't do any work. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(energy_dispersal)) Wikipedia article. It's disputed, but IMHO it's more fundamental talk about entropy in terms of energy rather than statistical mechanics or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this is so, but this is not a law of thermodynamics (I probably read that in a book by Landau), so there are exceptions. See, e.g., Solid State Communications,
Volume 21, Issue 1, January 1977, Pages 57–60, "New phase transition with increasing symmetry on cooling in barium sodium niobate".